# Retrieving Custom Layout dimensions before setContentView()

Tags: android, eclipse, android-custom-view

I am trying to draw a Custom View and have it inside a Scroll View. The way I did it is define the Custom View and add it inside a Linear Layout, which is itself located inside a Scroll View.

Problem: When I try to add the Custom View to the Linear Layout in onCreate(), I have to send dimensions of the Custom View with the addView() command. I don't know how much space the Custom View will be occupying on different devices so I can't send any values unless they are explicit integer values which I want to avoid since I want the View to be adaptable to different devices.

Question: How can I get the dimensions, or future dimensions, of the Custom View before setContentView() is run?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int screenWidth;
    int screenHeight;

    int viewWidth;
    int viewHeight;

    public class DrawView extends View {

        Rect[][] ctgRect = new Rect[3][11];

        Paint whitePaint;
        Paint blackPaint;

        int ctgRectWidth;
        int ctgRectHeight;
        int padding;

        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            setVariables(canvas);
            setPaint();

            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            drawRects(canvas);

        }

        protected void drawRects(Canvas canvas) { //Irrelevant to question          
            int currentPixelPos = 0;

            for (int x = 1; x < 11; x++) {
                canvas.drawRect(0 + padding, currentPixelPos + padding, 0 + padding + ctgRectWidth, 
                        currentPixelPos + padding + ctgRectHeight, blackPaint);

                currentPixelPos += (padding + ctgRectHeight);
            }

            currentPixelPos = 0;

            for (int x = 1; x < 11; x++) {
                canvas.drawRect(0 + padding + ctgRectWidth + padding, currentPixelPos + padding, 
                        screenWidth - padding, 
                        currentPixelPos + padding + ctgRectHeight, blackPaint);

                currentPixelPos += (padding + ctgRectHeight);
            }
        }

        protected void setVariables(Canvas canvas) { //Irrelevant to question
            screenWidth = canvas.getWidth();
            screenHeight = canvas.getHeight();

            padding = (int) (canvas.getWidth() * 0.0085);
            ctgRectWidth =  (int) ((screenWidth - (padding * 3)) / 2);
            ctgRectHeight = (int) ((ctgRectWidth / 2));
        }

        protected void setPaint() { //Irrelevant to question
            whitePaint = new Paint();
            whitePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            blackPaint = new Paint();
            blackPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(new DrawView(this));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLinearLayout);
        DrawView customView = new DrawView(this);
        layout.addView(customView, questionVariableWidth, questionVariableHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Thanks to anyone who replies.

Comment: I really haven't looked at your custom view but can't you just supply `LayoutParams` with `WRAP_CONTENT` as height and width?

Comment: @XaverKapeller, Already tried that. For some reason, the CustomView does not show up if I do that.

Comment: Most likely because with `WRAP_CONTENT` it has a size of 0. You just have to either correctly implement your custom view so `WRAP_CONTENT` works or use some fixed size. You can at least use the width of the `LinearLayout` as width constraint for your custom view.

Comment: The width is not a problem. The height of the Custom View is based on the width, so I COULD calculate it during onCreate() but I was looking for an easier way. But I can't use a fixed size because it would have to be different for each device.

Comment: Well you should calculate it in your `View`, not in `onCreate()`. But if it is based on the width your problem of different devices goes away. Your second option is that you could use a constant amount of dp and convert them to pixel on each device.

Comment: The setContentView() is run before the Custom View is generated, so I can't calculate it in my Custom View, correct?

Comment: Sure you can. Why not? Use the lifecycle callbacks of the view. The measure process is used to determine a View's size. The same happens when you add any view programmatically. As soon as they are added to the layout they are measured and determine there own size etc.

Comment: The first tutorial that I could find that explains this whole process and how to implement it in a custom view is this: http://www.jayway.com/2012/12/12/creating-custom-android-views-part-4-measuring-and-how-to-force-a-view-to-be-square/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @XaverKapeller for replying, but I found a solution. If anyone else runs into this problem: I calculated the screen width and used that to size my custom view.

I attached the function that I used to do this. The variables are self explanatory.

```
public void setDimensionVars() { //Retrieve/set dimensions for components
    DisplayMetrics displaySpecs = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaySpecs);

    screenWidth = displaySpecs.widthPixels;
    screenHeight = displaySpecs.heightPixels;
    padding = (int) (screenWidth * 0.0085);

    rectWidth = (int) ((screenWidth - (padding * 3)) / 2);
    rectHeight = (int) (rectWidth / 2);

    viewWidth = screenWidth;
    viewHeight = (0 + padding + rectHeight) * ((int) (Math.ceil((float) NUM_OF_CATEGORIES / 2)));
}
```

Hope it helps.